# Error E575 when starting VIM

Tags: neovim, error

When I start `vim` on my Mac using `iterm` or `MacVim` I receive the following error message:

```
E575: viminfo: Illegal starting char in line: ^A<ce>^Y^C<f1>H<85><a9>generator<c4>^Dnvim<a7>version<c4>^KNVIM v0.4.3<a9>max_kbyte
E575: viminfo: Illegal starting char in line: <a3>pid<cd>^I^Q<a8>encoding<c4>^Eutf-8^C
E575: viminfo: Illegal starting char in line: <ce>^X^I<86>I<83><a1>f<c4>>/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.4.3/share/nvim/runtime/doc/nvim.txt<a1>l^G<a1>c^N^D<ce>^W<b6><d9>^M<92>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

But when I press ENTER `vim` starts. I have deleted `.viminfo` file at the `home` folder. I suspect that it has something to do with `neovim`but I am not sure.

Comment: Does your vimrc override the location of the viminfo file? What does `:set viminfofile?` return? Does the problem happen if you start Vim with `vim -i NONE`? Or `vim -i ~/.viminfo`?

Comment: `:set viminfofile` returns `viminfofile=`. And when I start Vim with `vim -i NONE` or `vim -i ~/.viminfo` the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: @filbranden Yes, `vimrc` set the location of `viminfo` file in ' ~/.vim/dirs'. I deleted `viminfo` and now everything seems fine.

Comment: Please post an answer with what fixed it for you. If possible, include the snippet in your vimrc that was setting the path to the viminfo file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the `vimrc` file the following snippet overrides the location of the `viminfo` file from the `home` folder to `~/.vim/dirs` folder:

```
set viminfo+=n~/.vim/dirs/viminfo
```

So, deleting the `viminfo`file in this folder solves this error.